# Error parsing openzeppelin. Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition

Tags: solidity, truffle, openzeppelin

None of the solutions that I saw solved this issue. When I do `truffle compile` I get this error

> Error parsing @openzeppelin/contracts/GSN/Context.sol:
> ParsedContract.sol:15:1: ParserError: Expected pragma, import
> directive or contract/interface/library definition. abstract contract
> Context { ^------^

Should I be looking somewhere else? or do I have to install something?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
```

Comment: You are importing an openzeppelin version that is not compatible with the solc version you are using. Check the version supported by that openzeppelin version and either upgrade solc or downgrade openzeppelin. If you indicate which solc are you using I can suggest a compatible version.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I did "install truffle" and "brew solc" almost at the same time, and suddenly it was solved. I wasn't sure which of the two were the reason. It might be also that I didn't even have installed solc? thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

try downgrade openzepplin, i think you are trying some very old tutorial. i meet same case.

```
$npm install openzeppelin-solidity@v2.0.0
```